# Android check device IMEI is valid

Tags: java, android

in my application we use device `imei` and return some result base on that. i cant find any solution to validate phone imei, user can be use some emulator such as Genymotion, my app must be detect that and if user is using emulators i must be don't post data to server, how can i validate imei?

this solution on `PHP` work fine, but i can't find equivalent like with that on java for android

```
function is_luhn($n) {
    $str = '';
    foreach (str_split(strrev((string) $n)) as $i => $d) {
        $str .= $i %2 !== 0 ? $d * 2 : $d;
    }
    return array_sum(str_split($str)) % 10 === 0;
}
function is_imei($n){
    return is_luhn($n) && strlen($n) == 15;
}
```

Comment: is emulator giving you IMEI?

Comment: @Amy yes, its some times, some emulators are return maybe `000000000000000` or null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
public boolean isValidImei(String s){
        long n = Long.parseLong(s);
        int l = s.length();

        if(l!=15) // If length is not 15 then IMEI is Invalid
            return false;
        else
        {
            int d = 0, sum = 0;
            for(int i=15; i>=1; i--)
            {
                d = (int)(n%10);

                if(i%2 == 0)
                {
                    d = 2*d; // Doubling every alternate digit
                }

                sum = sum + sumDig(d); // Finding sum of the digits

                n = n/10;
            }

            System.out.println("Output : Sum = "+sum);

            if(sum%10==0 && sum!=0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
}
```

sumDig Function

```
int sumDig(int n) // Function for finding and returning sum of digits of a number
{
   int a = 0;
   while(n>0)
   {
       a = a + n%10;
       n = n/10;
   }
   return a;
}
```

Comment: whats `n` and `op` ?

Comment: You can check that is string numeric.

For example: 
 `if (l != 15 || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(s)) // If length is not 15 and digit then IMEI is Invalid`

In addition, "long n = Long.parseLong (s);" it is necessary to enclose the line in "else" block.